# Can the ASP.NET Yellow Screen of Death (YSOD) be generated on demand or captured?

Tags: asp.net, error-reporting, error-logging, yellow-screen-of-death

We'd like to just capture the YSOD output to use in an erorr reporting email, from a Global.asax error handler, for instance. Is there any way of leveraging the built-in ysod generator?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes there is a way that you can do this.

In the Application_Error event in the global.asax file, get the last exception as an System.HttpUnhandledException.  Your code will look like this:

```
var lastException = Server.GetLastError() as HttpUnhandledException;
string Ysod = lastException.GetHtmlErrorMessage();
// your call to emailing routine follows
```

I agree with other people's comments.  You can also do this with ELMAH.

Comment: 3 years on and who knows why I didn't want to use ELMAH, but this is  the answer I was certainly looking for. Didn't want to take another dependency in a busy project already overflowing with 3rd party modules I guess.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for as well, I use Elmah in my project, but in the case when the user is a administrator, I want to show the detailed YSOD not just the friendly error message.

Comment: I used Elmah, on other projects, but in this case specifically, I want to control error logging, because sh!t just got too serious, even for Elmah! This answers the original question properly and still stands today *sigh*

Answer (score 9):

I would look into [ELMAH (Error Logging Modules and Handlers for ASP.NET)](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/):

> ELMAH (Error Logging Modules and
>   Handlers) is an application-wide error
>   logging facility that is completely
>   pluggable. It can be dynamically added
>   to a running ASP.NET web application,
>   or even all ASP.NET web applications
>   on a machine, without any need for
>   re-compilation or re-deployment.
>
> Once ELMAH has been dropped into a
>   running web application and configured
>   appropriately, you get the following
>   facilities without changing a single
>   line of your code:
>
> - Logging of nearly all unhandled exceptions.
> - A web page to remotely view the entire log of recoded exceptions.
> - A web page to remotely view the full details of any one logged
>     exception.
> - In many cases, you can review the original yellow screen of death
>     that ASP.NET generated for a given
>     exception, even with customErrors mode
>     turned off.
> - An e-mail notification of each error at the time it occurs.
> - An RSS feed of the last 15 errors from the log.

Comment: It looks like ELMAH was moved to [GitHub](https://github.com/elmah/Elmah), but there's no information about this on the (original) Google Code archive.

Answer (score 3):

Have you heard of ELMAH ? It might give you all the features you really want...

Here is a blog post that explains a bit about it : http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You should check out [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) it does what you are asking automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I would say in general, you do not want the user to experience the YSOD.  This is something I've put in web apps before to capture the error and then allow for a more graceful error page to the user...

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
    HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

    msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("me@me.com"));
    msg.From = new MailAddress("from@me.com");
    msg.Subject = "My app had an issue...";
    msg.Priority = MailPriority.High;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(ctx.Request.Url.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine);
    sb.Append("Source:" + System.Environment.NewLine + ctx.Server.GetLastError().Source.ToString());
    sb.Append("Message:" + System.Environment.NewLine + ctx.Server.GetLastError().Message.ToString());
    sb.Append("Stack Trace:" + System.Environment.NewLine + ctx.Server.GetLastError().StackTrace.ToString());
    msg.Body = sb.ToString();

    //CONFIGURE SMTP OBJECT
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("myhost");

    //SEND EMAIL
    smtp.Send(msg);

    //REDIRECT USER TO ERROR PAGE
    Server.Transfer("~/ErrorPage.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Application_Error event in the Global.asax file is triggered whenever an unhandled exception occurs in the application. You can grab the last exception that occurred using the Server.GetLastError() method.

Similarly, you could create your own custom error page by specifying it in the web.config under the customErrors section in the web.config file. By specifying a default file, you can do any custom coding when an exception is routed there.